# in Action method dropdownlist parameter instead of getting string value it is getting index value,how to solve it. in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my view

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication.Models.Programs>
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "AddProgram";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/BasicLayout.cshtml";
}
<h2>AddProgram</h2>
<form method="post">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>@Html.Label("DepartmentName", "Department")</td>
        <td style="height:120px; width:320px">
          @Html.DropDownList("DepartName", (SelectList)ViewBag.Dept,"Select Department");
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>@Html.Label("ProgrameLevel", "Program Level")</td>
         <td>
           @Html.DropDownList("ProgrameName", (SelectList)ViewBag.DProgram, "---Select Program---");
         </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>@Html.Label("ProgramName", "Enter Program Name")</td>
         <td><input id="txt_ProgramName", type="text" name="programname" /></td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
  <div style="margin-left:80px">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddProgram()
{
  var dept = (from x in db.Departments select new { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name }).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
  ViewBag.Dept = new SelectList(dept, "Id", "Name");
  List<String> Ptype = new List<string>();
  Ptype.Add("BS");
  Ptype.Add("MS");
  ViewBag.DProgram = new SelectList(Ptype);
  return PartialView()
}
```

dropdownlist instead of getting string value it returns index value to parameter. How to get only  `enter code here` string value from dropdownlist? I search on browser but I couldn't find proper answer, Please answer it to solve...`
     [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIxy0.png

Comment: add what ever code you written for ViewBag.Dept in controller level

Comment: check image i attached it ..

Comment: There is no relationship btween control code and view level code.You have not declared viewBag.Dept in controller but in dropdown you are binding ViewBag.Dept..great!!!!!!

Comment: Here is Getting Code...

Comment: [HttpGet]                                                  public ActionResult AddProgram(){
              var dept = (from x in db.Departments
               select new  { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name }).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
ViewBag.Dept = new SelectList(dept, "Id", "Name");
            List<String> Ptype = new List<string>();
            Ptype.Add("BS");
            Ptype.Add("MS");
            ViewBag.DProgram = new SelectList(Ptype); return PartialView() }

Comment: Tick right mark,If answer helps @user3500386 .

Comment: @Shankar your answer want help. Actually you have to do ViewBag.dept = new SelectList(deptData, "Name", "Name"); in order to get deptname as value in action.

Answer (score 0):

```
var deptData= new[] {
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Dept1", Value = "1" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Dept2", Value = "2" },  
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Dept3", Value = "3" }  
  };
ViewBag.dept = new SelectList(deptData, "Text", "Text");

@Html.DropDownList("DepartName", (SelectList)ViewBag.Dept,"Select Department");
```

Specific to you example

```
// Here you only have to get name
var dept = (from x in db.Departments select new { Name = x.Name }).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList(); 
ViewBag.Dept = new SelectList(dept, "Name", "Name");
```

Comment: Why would you create an array of `SelectListItem` and then recreate it  again by calling `new SelectList(..)`?

Comment: SelectList and SelectListItem both are different thing. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem(v=vs.118).aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: I know, but I'm referring to array of `SelectListItem`! `SelectList` **is** `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (what your doing is pointless). All that needed here is `List<string> items = new List<string>() { "Dept1", "Dept2", "Dept3" }; ViewBag.dept = new SelectList(items)`

Comment: As per my thinking SelectList is container of any IEnumerable. Your case is correct if it does not want to switch to text or value. For future proof it is always good to keep text and value so you can play around value or text.

Comment: OP question is clear - the value should be the same as the text. And there is no point ever creating a `SelectList` from `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. You would just use `@Html.DropDownList("DepartName", (IEnumarable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Dept)` if you wanted the value and the text

Comment: @StephenMuecke - While I agree with you that `SelectList` is pointless here, because `DropDownListFor` does not have an overload that uses SelectList (it just converts it to an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`), Select list is more than just an IEnumerable... just not useful in this situation.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch, Agreed. What I meant by _is_ was the inheritance hierarchy.